# Parallel plate capacitor infinite energy

Tags: electrostatics, energy-conservation, perpetual-motion, ions, ionization-energy

Imagine a system with a parallel plate capacitor with holes in the middle where the plates are charged before being disconnected and insulated. Neutral atoms are introduced between the plates and are subsequently ionized in some way. The created ions will gain momentum and travel through the hole after which their kinetic energy can be collected. As long as the kinetic energy gained by the ions is higher than the ionization energy we just gained energy. I know that this should not be possible so where am I wrong?

Comment: How you want to move the plates faster than the accelerating ions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @secr no plates are moving. The atoms are ionized by some unspecified method and the ions will move towards one plate before passing through the hole

Comment: @symenschilstra so after they pass the hole, they'll move at constant speed

Comment: @secr yes and than they will be caught in some way to harness their kinetic energy

Comment: @symenschilstra So why is the energy infinite?

Comment: @secr I got more energy out than I put in. If I now recombine the electrons and the the ions I can do it all over again and keep gaining energy

Comment: @symenschilstra And who is charging the plates?

Comment: @secr what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the capacitor has voltage $V$ and charge $Q = CV$. Let's assume that a positive charge $+q$ and a negative charge $-q$ are created halfway between the plates, with $q\ll Q$ (and equal mass, for simplicity). The positive charge reaches the negative plate and vice versa. At the instant this happens, the combined kinetic energy of the charges is $qV$ (actually slightly less because separating the charges requires some energy). Since the charges are effectively part of the part of the plates they have just reached, they cause the capacitor charge to decrease by $q$, and hence the electrostatic energy of the capacitor by $qV$. Thus the total energy is the same as before ionization, apart from the ionization energy you've put in.

In other words, you have not gained any energy for free. If you harvest the kinetic energy, you still need to remove the charges from the system, which requires work. If you don't remove them, then the capacitor charge will go down, so in effect all you are doing is extract energy from a charged capacitor in a convoluted way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I understand correctly you say that the ions and electrons will go on top of the capacitors and slowly discharge them. I have however seen parallel plate capacitors with holes in the middle which I believe work similar to electron guns. The ions wil now not hit the plates and the plates will stay charged. How will this effect the result?

Comment: @symenschilstra The arguments above doesn't necessarily require hole-free plates, they apply to plates with a hole (or grids). What do you do with the charge after you extract its kinetic energy once it's passed through the hole? To remove it from the system (i.e. take it out of the hole and move it far away) you still need to do an equal amount of work. If you don't remove it (i.e. if the charge were to stay in the hole), it is still contributing to the capacitor E-field. So in effect it is still part of the capacitor, and reduces the total charge on the plate.

Answer (score 0):

A system's energy, which is conserved when the system is closed, is the sum of the kinetic and potential energy. You've forgot to take the potential energy, namely $\Delta x Eq$, into account.